# How I list table name in mysql into combobox using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I want to list table name in mysql database into combobox winform C#.
I use this SQL query in phpmyadmin, and it return me the results I want.

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%nh%'
```

And then I try to write the function in C#. Here is my code

```
void get_table()
    {
        string myConnection = "Server=localhost;Database=sctv_data;Port=3306;User ID=root;Password=;Charset=utf8";
        string query = "SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%nh%'";
        conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDatabase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDatabase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            cb_data_name.Items.Clear();
            if (myReader.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    cb_chon.Items.Add((string)myReader[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        } 
    }
```

But it fail; I think it have a problem, but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: What do you mean by _it fails_? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: What exception you are getting? and your catch block is evil. Catch block are meant to catch exceptions not swallowing them silently. refer this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234278/good-ratio-of-catch-statements-to-lines-of-code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SqlDataAdapter`

```
void get_table()
{
    string myConnection = "Server=localhost;Database=sctv_data;Port=3306;User ID=root;Password=;Charset=utf8";
    string query = "SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%nh%'";
    conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDatabase);
    MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter;
    try
    {
        conDatabase.Open();
        myAdapter= new mySqlAdapter(cmdDataBase);
        cb_data_name.Items.Clear();
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        mySqlAdapter.Fill(dt);
        cb_data_name.DatSource=dt;
        cb_data_name.DisplayMemeber="table_name";
    }
    catch
    {

    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry but seem " string myConnection = "Server=localhost;Database=sctv_data;Port=3306;User ID=root;Password=;Charset=utf8";" not effect, it seem list all data table in mysql @Ullas